# Why does this code yield unexpected output?

Tags: java, jtable

I have a table. In the first column. I have students' names, such as "Esfandyar Talebi" and "Arash Nouri"; the number of rows can be changed.
Just 2 rows are filled from 4 rows.

The code that I have written:

```
List<String> professorsName = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0; i < InformationTable.getRowCount(); i++) {
    professorsName.add((String) InformationTable.getValueAt(i, 0));
    System.out.println(professorsName.toString());
}
```

But this is the output:

> [Esfandyar Talebi]
>
> [Esfandyar Talebi, Arash Nouri]
>
> [Esfandyar Talebi, Arash Nouri, null]
>
> [Esfandyar Talebi, Arash Nouri, null, null]
>
> [Esfandyar Talebi, Arash Nouri, null, null, null]
>
> [Esfandyar Talebi, Arash Nouri, null, null, null, null]
>
> null

Comment: Is InformationTable.getRowCount() == 6 ?

Comment: no this table has just 4 rows.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently your `InformationTable.getValueAt(i, 0)` returns `null` for certain values of `i`. You'll have to look at your TableModel

Answer (score 1):

There are probably 6 rows in the InformationTable. You probably first have to check wether the cell has been filled with a name:

```
List<String> professorsNames = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0; i < InformationTable.getRowCount(); i++) {
    String name = (String) InformationTable.getValueAt(i, 0);
    if (name != null && name.trim().length() != 0) {
        professorsNames.add(name);
        System.out.println("Adding: " + name);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Refusing: " + name);
    }
}

System.out.println("Found: " + professorsNames.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing strange with the loop you posted... It runs as many times as the value InformationTable.getRowCount() method returns, which appears to be six. So the problem is likely on the InformationTable class, you may need to post it if you need further help.